# How to apply NADA package (censtats) in a nested database in R

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to improve my R code by removing plenty of for loops.
I would like to apply censtats from the NADA package to all of my data, grouped by several factor.

Here is an example of my code (with the for loops) using a simple database :

```
Data <- data.frame("A"=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"), "B" = c("c","c","c","d","c","c","d","d"),"X"=c(2,1,3,1,1,2,1,1), "Y"=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE), Z = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0))

Data_calc <- data.frame( #create empty database to increment at each loop
"K-M"=numeric(),check.names=FALSE, #result of censtats
                 MLE=numeric(), #result of censtats
                 ROS=numeric(), #result of censtats
                 A=factor(),
                 B=factor(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

List_A <- unique(Data$A) 
List_B <- unique(Data$B)

for (a in seq_along(List_A)){ 
  for (b in seq_along(List_B)){ 

    Temp <- subset(Data, A == List_A[a] & B == List_B[b]) # subset by A and B

    if (nrow(Temp) > 1){ #condition 1 recquired by censtats
      if (Temp$Z > 0) { #condition 2 recquired by censtats

    Temp <- censtats(Temp$X, Temp$Y) #formating the results
    Temp$myNames <- rownames(Temp)
    Temp<- spread(Temp[c(2,4)], myNames, mean)
    Temp$A <- List_A[a]
    Temp$B <- List_B[b]

    Data_calc <- bind_rows(Data_calc, Temp)
      } else {}
   } else {}  }}
```

This is the results we obtain :

```
> Data_calc
       K-M      MLE      ROS A B
1 2.333333 1.977163 1.991738 a c
2 2.000000 1.369061 2.000000 b c
```

In order to improve my code, I would like to remove the loops by grouping the factor using nest().

```
Data_nest <- nest(group_by(Data, A, B))

> Data_nest
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  A     B     data            
  <fct> <fct> <list>          
1 a     c     <tibble [3 x 3]>
2 a     d     <tibble [1 x 3]>
3 b     c     <tibble [2 x 3]>
4 b     d     <tibble [2 x 3]>
```

I'm stuck here as before using censtats I have to apply conditions 1 and 2 but I cannot find how to apply the conditions row by row.

Could anyone tell me the best solution (with or without nest) to improve the code as in reality my database has 4 factors and almost 2000 rows containing a list and the loop method take lot of time.

Thanks in advance.